# rpy2 load multiple DataFrames from a .RData file into pandas

Tags: python, r, dataframe, rpy2

I have an `.RData` file in the system which contains three objects - all R-`DataFrame`s. I would like to load them into python as pandas DataFrames. The problem I get is, that the objects are not loaded via `rpy`, only their names:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import pandas as pd
file="./normalization.RData"
rf = r.load(file)
rf

<StrVector - Python:0x7fdf1a28cb08 / R:0x4ce82c8>
['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

f1[2]

'annodf'
In [11]:
```

Either only the names are loaded, or I do not understand how to access/convert the DFs from the RData.

Does somebody have the solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok - I just realized that the object are not really loaded into `rf` variable, but into the `rpy2.rojbects.r` which represents the R-environment.. that is tricky!

Therefore the following works:

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import r
import rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri as pandas2ri


#load into the env
file="./normalization.RData"
rf=r['load'](file)
rf

<StrVector - Python:0x7fdf1a28cb08 / R:0x4ce82c8>
['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

#acces file in env and convert
df2=pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(r['df2'])
type(df2)

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: I get the following error when using your answer directly: `AttributeError: module 'rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri' has no attribute 'ri2py_dataframe'`

Answer (score 0):

For those who get below error:

`AttributeError: module 'rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri' has no attribute 'ri2py_dataframe'`

change this:

```
df2 = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(r['df2'])
```

to this:

```
df2 = rpy2.robjects.conversion.rpy2py(r['df2'])
```

Used R version: 3.6.3

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31994302)